# Extjs window/iframe getBody mask/unmask

Tags: extjs, window, mask

I have a gridpanel with some buttons for each row in the panel. When clicking the buttons, a new Ext.window pops up loading a remote url . Since the remote URL is opened in an iframe, I cannot use Ext.getBody().mask in the parent grid and Ext.getBody().unmask in the iframe, because these are two different pages. The reason I want to do it like this (Ext.getBody().mask in the parent page, and the unmask in the iframe) is because the url loaded in the iframe has a lot of js and images being loaded in the  section. Therefore if i use the mask and unmask in the iframe, it will still take a lot of time to load whats in the iframe header, until it gets to the point where I can use the Ext.getBody().mask

My question is: can Ext.getBody().unmask() be used somehow on the parent window? (to hide the mask opened from the parent)?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2):

try running `window.parent.Ext.getBody().unmask()` from the iframe.

I assume your iframe has the same origin as the parent.